# Would it be worth separating Xbox 360 Kinect & Xbox One Kinect questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently, [kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinect) is being used for both the Xbox 360 and the Xbox One Kinect. We should probably separate them out. Why?

1. These are different devices with different capabilities, and aren't cross-compatible. Not to mention that the Xbox 360 Kinect was an addon peripheral, whereas *every* Xbox One console comes with an Xbox One Kinect.
2. Xbox 360 Kinect questions will become less relevant over time. As the Xbox One Kinect has it's own issues and quirks due to point 1, it wouldn't be relevant suggesting related questions or closing with questions for the Xbox 360 Kinect.

Now there's [only 5 questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinect+xbox-one) currently tagged with [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one) and [kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinect) at the moment, so it'll be a quick fix if we nip it in the bud now.

I propose:

- Re-tagging the current Xbox One Kinect questions with [xbox-one-kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one-kinect)
- Re-tagging the rest of the [kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinect) questions to [xbox-360-kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360-kinect). There's a few of them, probably best for a batch-job.

Eventually, the [kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinect) tag should probably become a synonym of [xbox-one-kinect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one-kinect). It's still early days yet, and we can cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: Is there a reason for Kinect to be it's own tag?  Given that it is console-specific wouldn't just tagging with console tag be sufficient?  It kinda feels like if we had made tags for xbox-controller and xbox-360-controller when the 360 came out.

Comment: @Batophobia - the difference with controllers is that the controller didn't *change* much when upgrading - the kinects have different voice commands, different levels of sophistication regarding movement (the Xbox one can discern individual fingers for example). They are radically different technology from one another. Its also still a peripheral, which some people may use frequently, and some not. Having extensive Xbox one knowledge does not mean you know everything about a Xboxone kinect, so iI think its a subject area worth keeping as a separate tag

Comment: But they are both still kinects. As far as I know, we tag xbox controllers, playstation controllers and even joysticks with controllers tag. Based on the [tag wiki](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/controllers/info) we should be using controllers for kinect too! The whole controllers mess should be cleaned up first..

Comment: @3ventic - there are literally thousands of controllers out there. That's why we have the one combined tag - general controller knowledge (troubleshooting, x-input vs d-input etc) is all generally the same. There are only two kinects (well 3, if you count kinect for windows), and they are fairly different. Knowledge of one does not necessarily translate to knowledge of the other

Comment: @Robotnik I would argue that Kinect is merely a fancy controller type.  In fact, current [controller tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/controllers/info) even confirms this.  Frankly I think keyboard, mouse, controller, kinect, etc. should get grouped into a common tag of "input-device" or something anyway.  Additionally, I think controllers follow your logic of "knowledge of one does not necessarily translate to knowledge of the other".  Knowing the N64 controller does not mean you know the PS4 controller.

Comment: Are there any [tag:kinect] questions about the XBO kinect that aren't tagged with [tag:xbox-one]? There don't seem to be.

Comment: @TZHX - not that I can see, they're all tagged with either xbox-one or xbox-360